# Unable to send chatMessage with Teams Graph API php

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

With help from @CarlZhao I am finally getting a good understanding of the difference between OAuth and Graph. I am building the capability in my app for users to post messages to a team channel. So far I can list teams, channels, and delete channels. I am having a hard time trying to send a `chatMessage`. I understand that because sending a chatMessage is a `delegated permission` and not an `application permission` so from my understanding I have to use the `accessToken` created from OAuth when the user authenticated with my app.

What I am doing is saving that token in my database so I can call it when I am trying to send a `chatMessage`. Not sure if that is correct. So in my code, I am creating a new Graph instance, but I am using the access token of the user and not the token of the graph.

```
$useraccesstoken = "************************************";

// create a new OAuth graph from useraccesstoken
$graph_message = new Graph();
$graph_message->setAccessToken($useraccesstoken);

// post message
$data = [
    'body' => [
        'content' => 'This is a message from the API I made it works'
    ],
];
$message = $graph_message->createRequest("POST", "/teams/$group_id/channels/$channel_id/messages")
                ->addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))
                ->attachBody($data)
                ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                ->execute();
```

This is producing no errors, but nothing happens and the `chatMessage` is not posted. I have double-checked and my `$group_id` and `$channel_id` are correct.

Am I using the `$useraccesstoken` correctly? can I start a new `Graph()` instance with the `$useraccesstoken`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could start a new Graph() instance with the $useraccesstoken.

The [graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) of sending messages doesn't return `User::class`. Try your code with

```
->setReturnType(Model\ChatMessage::class)
```

The access token is invalid for one hour by default, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#access-tokens). You could not use it all the time, so it seems you don't need to store in the database. It's better to refresh token before the access token expires, and this [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=3) shows you how to refresh token.

> The default is 1 hour - after 1 hour, the client must use the refresh
> token to (usually silently) acquire a new refresh token and access
> token.

Comment: Gotcha on the token refresh. Tried the chatmessage. No difference

Comment: Could you share how to get access token? Does the token work when using Postman?

Comment: You get the useraccesstoken from the authentication process when a user logs into your site with OAuth

Comment: One thing that I am learning is that there is a possibility that after assigning permission to an API you have to give it a minute or two before they seem to work. I was having weird inconsistent issues where it would work and then not work. I decided to add the permissions and walk away to get a cup of coffee and some food and when I got back it works and it keeps working.

Comment: Yes, it needs about 10mins after adding permissions. Could you test the access token with Postman to make sure it is correct? Then use it in the code:  `$message = $graph_message->createRequest("POST", "/teams/$group_id/channels/$channel_id/messages")
                ->attachBody($data)
                ->setReturnType(Model\ChatMessage::class)
                ->execute();`

Comment: Are you sure that `$graph_message` is coming from a Graph instance you initiated from your user access token?

Comment: The access token I mentioned is the token getting by [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). The code `$graph_message = new Graph();
$graph_message->setAccessToken($accesstoken);` is correct.

Comment: I got my code working now, it was the issue waiting for permissions to take effect I think.

Comment: Glad to know that:)